# How to call functions of SQLite for Windows Runtime from JavaScript App

Tags: javascript, sqlite, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I downloaded Precompiled Binaries for Windows Runtime from [sqlite.org](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html) and added to Reference of Windows Store JavaScript project. But I don't know the next step. Although I would like to call functions of this library by JavaScript, what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tim Heuer has a [javascript sample](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2012/08/07/updated-how-to-using-sqlite-from-windows-store-apps.aspx) at his blog - it uses the [SQLite3-WinRT](https://github.com/doo/SQLite3-WinRT) wrapper. The wrapper project site also has sample code.

Here is a snippet from the project site:

```
var dbPath = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current.localFolder.path + '\\db.sqlite';
SQLite3JS.openAsync(dbPath)
.then(function (db) {
    return db.runAsync('CREATE TABLE Item (name TEXT, price REAL, id INT PRIMARY KEY)')
    .then(function () {
    return db.runAsync('INSERT INTO Item (name, price, id) VALUES (?, ?, ?)', ['Mango', 4.6, 123]);
    })
    .then // ...
```

Disclaimer: I normally do C#, so I haven't used the above library.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It seems functions can't call directly from JavaScript. I'll use wrapper class.